# How to get image from an ImageButton?

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'm not sure about the code, but I tried doing this:

```
ImageButton stuff = (ImageButton) createView.findViewById(R.id.stuff);
int stuff2 = stuff.getId();
champs.setImageResource(stuff2);
```

But that didn't work, the Imagebutton was shrinked for some reason, there was no image, just a gray rectangle.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988753/copy-bitmap-contents-of-one-imageview-to-anoher) helps.

Answer (score 9):

try this

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)stuff.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Comment: why did i got this error : `android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable`

Answer (score 1):

```
stuff.getId();
```

This will return the `id` of the View not the image resource associated with it. So you won't be having a resource related to this that is why you are not seeing the `Image`.

Set a valid drawable to `setImageResource` Some thing like `R.drawable.drawable_id`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ID of drawable resource but you are setting `ID` of the `ImageButton` as image resource.

here `stuff.getId()` returns `R.id.stuff`.

set the valid drawable resource like

```
ImageButton stuff = (ImageButton) createView.findViewById(R.id.stuff);
stuff.setImageResource(R.drawable.id_of_image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ImageButton stuff = (ImageButton) createView.findViewById(R.id.stuff);
Drawable d = stuff .getBackground();
champs.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help get the drawable object and set the drawable object.You can also get the Bitmap object for image drawable This will set the exact drawable associated with the imagebutton

```
ImageButton mButton = new ImageButton(this);
Drawable drawable = mButton.getBackground();
champs.setImageDrawable(drawable)
```